# user control (.ascx) with a textbox and a ajax calendar extender - end date should be greater than start date

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control (.ascx) with textbox and ajax calendar extender . I used this twice for start date and end date in web forms. How to compare these dates using compare validator control? 
my code:

.ascx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDatePicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:ImageButton runat="Server" ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.png" AlternateText="Click to show calendar" /> 
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender Format="dd/MM/yyyy" ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="txtDatePicker" runat="server" PopupButtonID="Image1" />

.aspx

Start Date   <uc1:datePicker ID="datePickerSD" runat="server" >
End Date     <uc1:datePicker ID="datePickerED" runat="server"    />
 <asp:CompareValidator ID="compareValidatorDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="datePickerED.UniqueID"  ControlToCompare="datePickerSD.ClientID"  CultureInvariantValues="true" 
 ErrorMessage="End date should be greate than start date" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" SetFocusOnError="true" Type="Date"> </asp:CompareValidator>
```

getting error:

Comment: _"getting error:"_ ??

Answer (score 0):

you should use custom validator in which you specify javascript function that should be executed upon validation. in this function u can do whatever logic u want.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="custDateOfBirth"  runat="server"   ControlToValidate="txtBirthDate" ClientValidationFunction="CheckDate" ErrorMessage="Enter less than the current date" CssClass="ClsRedtext"  SetFocusOnError="true" Type="Date" ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: Control 'datePickerED' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'custCheckDate' cannot be validated.

Comment: Continue code from above :<asp:CustomValidator ID="custCheckDate"  runat="server"   ControlToValidate="datePickerED.ClientID" ClientValidationFunction="CheckDate" ErrorMessage="Enter less than the current date" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:CustomValidator> How to get date value from the datepicker usercontrol textbox?

Comment: try to get the client id from the browser using the debugger and place it manually and see if it still exists

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```html
<asp:CompareValidator ID="compareValidatorDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="datePickerED$txtDatePicker" ControlToCompare ="datePickerSD$txtDatePicker" CultureInvariantValues="true" 
                                            ErrorMessage="End date should be greater than start date" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" SetFocusOnError="false" Type="String" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CompareValidator>
```